# SQL - OUTER JOIN a UNION-ed tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union, outer-join

I am new to sql. I have three tables, I want to `UNION` the first two tables then `OUTER JOIN` the result with the third table and only selecting a desired date.

I have already done the `UNION` but I don't know how the `OUTER JOIN` will come in.

These are my tables:

```
TABLE_1

| ID   | Name     |
-------------------
| 1    | John     |
| 2    | Peter    |
```

```
TABLE_2

| ID   | Name     |
-------------------
| 3    | Anne     |
| 4    | May      |
```

```
TABLE_3

| ID   | Name     | Date       |
--------------------------------
| 2    | Peter    | 2019-02-13 |
| 3    | Anne     | 2019-02-12 |
| 4    | May      | 2019-02-13 |
```

This is my query right now that only combines `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM TABLE_1 UNION SELECT ID, Name FROM TABLE_2
```

I want the final result to return ID and Name from `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2` where the date in `TABLE_3` is `2019-02-13`.

I want it to look like this:

```
| ID   | Name     | Date       |
--------------------------------
| 2    | Peter    | 2019-02-13 |
| 4    | May      | 2019-02-13 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(
  SELECT ID, Name FROM TABLE_1 
  UNION
  SELECT ID, Name FROM TABLE_2
 ) AS A
 JOIN TABLE_3
 ON TABLE_3.ID = A.ID AND TABLE_3.DATE = "2019-02-13"
```

[DB Fiddle Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/knD6QthdaALodcfCNPDpNV/0)

Answer (score 1):

One approach here is to not use a union query, but instead to use exists subqueries to check for the existence of each `TABLE_3` record in either of the first two tables.

```
SELECT t3.ID, t3.Name, t3.Date
FROM TABLE_3 t3
WHERE
    t3.Date = '2019-02-13' AND (
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_1 t1 WHERE t1.ID = t3.ID) OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2 t2 WHERE t2.ID = t3.ID));
```

Comment: I wonder if it's intentional or coincidence that the `ID` values in `TABLE_3` match those in `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`...

Comment: @Nick Assuming we expect good table design, then it's _necessary_ that the IDs match, because in real life two or more people could have the same name.

Comment: That's a pretty big expectation on SO! :-) If true, it makes it somewhat pointless to have the name in `TABLE_3` which means it's bad table design.

Comment: Yes, the tables are not normalized.  Maybe the OP is expecting a name based solution, but someone else would also comment if I did that.

Comment: Not trying to be critical. Based on the accepted answer this would work perfectly.

Comment: @Nick You are right, I don't need the Name on the 3rd table. Thank you for pointing it out!